# Google Sheets Auto Date and Time Stamp on Multiple Columns

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I want my Google Sheet to automatically do the following:

- If the "Title" column is edited/updated --> then a Datestamp (mm-dd-yy) is inserted to the "Date" column;
- If the "Title" column is edited/updated --> then a Timestamp (hh:mm) is inserted into the "TimeStart" column; and
- If the "Description" column is edited/updated --> then a Timestamp (hh:mm) is inserted to the "TimeStop" column.

I have already added named ranges for Columns A through E as follows:

- Column A = Title
- Column B = Description
- Column C = Date
- Column D = TimeStart
- Column E = TimeStop.

I found a code that lets me do the datestamp/timestamp thing, but it only works for one column (from https://www.internetgeeks.org/tech/add-timestamp-time-stamp-google-docs-spreadsheet/):

```
function onEdit(event)
{ 
  var timezone = "PST";
  var timestamp_format = "MM-dd-yy";
  var updateColName = "Title";
  var timeStampColName = "Date";
  var sheet = event.source.getSheetByName('Sheet1');

  var actRng = event.source.getActiveRange();
  var editColumn = actRng.getColumn();
  var index = actRng.getRowIndex();
  var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var dateCol = headers[0].indexOf(timeStampColName);
  var updateCol = headers[0].indexOf(updateColName);
  updateCol = updateCol + 1;

  if (dateCol > -1 && index > 1 && editColumn == updateCol) { 
    var cell = sheet.getRange(index, dateCol + 1);
    var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timezone, timestamp_format);
    cell.setValue(date);
  }
}
```

I tried to copy and paste this same code over and over again and just change the values of the `updateColName`, `timeStampColName`, and `timestamp_format` variables.

And as I found out, you cannot just copy and paste multiple `onEdit` functions and expect it to run on the same document.

I've been trying to find a solution to this for a while now. I feel like I would've been able to figure this out if I knew even a little bit about coding, but I don't.

Here is a link to my Google Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_dW8erkzVJFT6aUiB-0SikeMTbCnXmoo3d5mgUBN910/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Start https://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is that you need to have the function looking for edits in three places.  Your current code is only looking for edits in your "Title" column.  I've added code to look for the other locations.

```
function onEdit(event)
{ 
  var timezone = "PST";
  var datestamp_format = "MM-dd-yy";
  var updateColName = "Title";
  var dateStampColName = "Date";
  var startEditColName = "TimeStart"; // edit column to signal time start
  var startTimeColName = "TimeStart";
  var stopEditColName = "TimeStop";  // edit column to signal time stop
  var stopTimeColName = "TimeStop";
  var sheet = event.source.getSheetByName('Sheet1');


  var actRng = event.source.getActiveRange();
  var editColumn = actRng.getColumn();
  var index = actRng.getRowIndex();
  var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var dateCol = headers[0].indexOf(dateStampColName);
  var updateCol = headers[0].indexOf(updateColName); updateCol = updateCol+1;
  if (dateCol > -1 && index > 1 && editColumn == updateCol) { 
    var cell = sheet.getRange(index, dateCol + 1);
    var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timezone, datestamp_format);
    cell.setValue(date);
  }

  var startCol = headers[0].indexOf(startTimeColName);
  var startEditCol = headers[0].indexOf(startEditColName); startEditCol = startEditCol+1;
  if (startCol > -1 && index > 1 && editColumn == startEditCol) { 
    var cell1 = sheet.getRange(index, startCol + 1);
    var date = new Date();
    var startTime = date.toTimeString();
    cell1.setValue(startTime);
  }

    var stopCol = headers[0].indexOf(stopTimeColName);
  var stopEditCol = headers[0].indexOf(stopEditColName); stopEditCol = stopEditCol+1;
  if (stopCol > -1 && index > 1 && editColumn == stopEditCol) { 
    var cell2 = sheet.getRange(index, stopCol + 1);
    var date = new Date();
    var stopTime = date.toTimeString();
    cell2.setValue(stopTime);
  }
}
```

I've also added this to your 'TimeStamp' script file as a separate script - Date_Timestamp.gs, so you can see the functionality.

This isn't pretty by any means, but it does what you asked.  Let me know if you need more explanation or if I didn't answer your question.

Comment: Ron, thank you so much for taking the time to help me out. I used your code on that google sheet, but it didn't work. I even tried to use it on a completely new google sheet with the same settings and same code, but it still wouldn't work. The only thing that worked was the "Date" Column, but the "TimeStart" and "TimeStop" columns did not work. Any suggestions as to what may be wrong?

Comment: I am soooo sorry! I messed up. Now I see what the issue is. I did not correctly present what I really wanted. Here is what I really need: - If the "Title" column is edited/updated --> then a Datestamp (mm-dd-yy) is inserted to the "Date" column;
 - If the "Title" column is edited/updated --> then a Timestamp (hh:mm) is inserted into the "TimeStart" column; and
 - If the "Description" column is edited/updated --> then a Timestamp (hh:mm) is inserted to the "TimeStop" column.

Comment: Ron, never mind on everything. It actually worked! Using your code, all I had to do was change the StartEditColumn and the StopEditColumn. Thank you so much again for your help!

Comment: Ron, would you mind helping me with one small tiny detail with this? The TimeStamp returns a time in the following format: 14:49:56 GMT-0700 (PDT) ... Is there a way I can have it return a time in this format: 14:49:56

Comment: Narek, change the `startTime` and `stopTime` lines to the following: `var startTime = (date.getHours() + ":" + date.getMinutes() + ":" + date.getSeconds());` and `var stopTime = (date.getHours() + ":" + date.getMinutes() + ":" + date.getSeconds());`.

Comment: @RonKloberdanz: [warning](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258206/what-is-a-help-vampire)

Comment: Thanks @HovercraftFullOfEels.  I am new to this, so that is good information.  Whether it is a HV situation or not, I answered it as much for the OP as for myself.   I haven't seen anything else like this, it seemed like a question I could answer with my limited GAS/Javascript experience, I generated code that I will use myself, AND I learned a few things.